# Pros and cons for using native code in Java?

Tags: java, c++, c, native, native-code

I'm considering writing a Java application that might make use of native code(most likely written in c(++), not assembly), and I'd like to see pros and cons of doing so. I'm aware that native code is intended to be run on a specific machine/machine specs, as opposed to code being run by the JVM, which is of course a virtual machine. If I understand correctly, native code run on its native machine runs faster than bytecode, is this correct?

Basically, if I'm writing a program, is it worth it to use native code for certain computations and a few other functions to try to reduce the time it takes and the strain on the processor? Is there a reliable way to make it work on virtually all systems if I do use native code(if I have only my system to write/test the code on)?

Comment: Have you hit a problem where the only solution left is to write native code ? If not, don't do it.

Comment: pros : performance and cons : reduce platform independence.

Answer (score 5):

Judging from your question you are not at a stage where you have explored all the possibilities of a Java-only solution, have hit a brick wall, and are now looking for native code-based workarounds for your problem. Therefore the strong suggestion is to stay clear of solutions involving native code.

Keep in mind that the JVM does *not* naïvely interpret bytecode; it compiles it into optimized native code during runtime. You are very unlikely to experience performance issues with correctly written Java code.